# Show '0' if result is empty

Tags: sql

I try to calculate in SQL. The output of the calculation is showed in a chart. The chart stops working of there if the result of the sql query is empty:

This is the SQL query I am using:

```
SELECT SUM(total) as total
FROM table
WHERE user_id = 1 AND date BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-31'
```

If there is data in table there is no problem. When there is no data the chart stops working.

So I want to show a '0' if the total is empty. What do I need to change in my SQL query to show a '0' if it is empty?

Comment: Use isnull(SUM(total), 0)

Comment: Tag the dbms used, you've already got at least one product specific answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` to return 0 instead of NULL if the table is empty:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(total),0) as total
FROM table
WHERE user_id = 1 AND date BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(total), 0) as total
FROM table
WHERE user_id = 1 AND date BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

This query would always return exactly one row, defaulting to zero if there are no rows matching:

```
SELECT COALESCE((
  SELECT 
    SUM(total)
  FROM table
  WHERE user_id = 1 AND date BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-31'
),0) AS total
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
if not exists (SELECT total FROM table WHERE user_id = 1 AND date BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-31')
begin 
    select 0 as total
end
else
begin
    SELECT SUM(total) as total
    FROM table
    WHERE user_id = 1 AND date BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-06-31'
end
```